# How to copy file from etc to home?

Tags: gnome

I need to make a copy of /etc/default/grub file and put it in ~/backup/config/ directory In Gnome files.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what problem you are having?  Are you receiving an error message?

Answer (score 0):

This is the command. If you met with an error comment the error.

```
sudo cp -R /etc/default/grub /backup/config/grub
```